# Zephir on Windows and Linux (ubuntu) - errors

Tags: windows, ubuntu, zephir

Afters hours and hours spend on trying to install zephir on my windows 8, i finally managed to build an single .zep file !

Now, i've copied the .dll from /ext/Release directory, into my xampp/php/ext and added the extension=.dll in my php.ini - I'm using latest xampp with php 5.5.24 - and when I restart my Apache, the httpd.exe throws an error "The program can't start because php5.dll is missing form your computer". I'm really baffled by this eror, searching on net for the last hours and I can't find an answer !

Does anyone had this issue before ?

Problem 2) I've install vagrant and followed the tutorial from blog, and managed to install everything.Then I went to /vagrant directory as it is shared between the host and the guest, used zaphir init , all the files were generated, then copied my .zep file from my windows host into the right directory and runned zephir build. Again all went fine, the .so file was created but as my main development platform is on windows, i wanted to use the files from /etc/ to build the .dll extension for my xampp installation - to be honest i didn't tried to use the .so extension and test if the extension works on linux - .

Now, using the Developer Command Promt for Visual Studio 2012, i tried to run command "cl .c" inside the /ext/ directory that was build by zaphir on linux, but an fatal error its appearing in my developer command promt "Fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: php.h: No such file or directory"

The greatest way for me would be to compile the extension for both windows, my dev. pc but for linux also !

Could please someone help me with this issues ? Give me some guidance as I have to admit, I don't have knowledge about developing/compiling in C !

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you followed https://github.com/phalcon/zephir/blob/master/WINDOWS.md ?
I generally do not recommend xampp since it uses the TS version of PHP.

This means you generally have to replace anything in the manual 
containg NTS with TS.

(The most important part is that you download a devpack for TS insteadof NTS, as the manual specifies.)

Comment: I think I did ! Do you recommend a different easily to install windows server ? Some program that let me jump it into work fast ? At this moment I installed vagrant with ubuntu, set the web server with all the necessary modules, changed the webserver directory to the folder shared between host and guest /vagrant/app in my case, where in /app i have my website, then i setup vagrant and my host to allow incoming requests so I can develope inside /app but but to connect to the mysql from my host, avoiding setting up phpmyadmin + mysql on guest, then the host apache etc. Atm It's OK for me

Comment: You should be able to compile for your xampp using a TS debug pack.